# Printer wasn't working. Gave it a Static IP and now it works! But why?

Tags: networking, router, printer, dhcp, static-ip

I was toying with my printer to get it to work.

Originally, the printer was automatically given an IP of

(169.254.248.206)

However... I read that *manually* setting the printer's IP outside my router's DHCP range

(192.168.1.100  - 192.168.1.149)

Could fix it.

And it did! But I don't know much about Computer Networks, so could someone explain why this happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP address 169.254.248.206 is not on the same subnet as 192.168.1.xxx.

Additionally, 169.254.1.0 through to 169.254.254.255 are [Link-Local addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address).

Comment: Just to add that it probably wasn't 'given' the 169 address, it would have been self-assigned because for some reason it couldn't find the DHCP server.